# Why is this condition not working? - if in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to prescribe a condition if selected kind of product. I'm trying to prescribe a condition `if` in template. But I'm doing something wrong. Helps me, please.

**views.py**

```
def product_list(request, category=None, subcategory=None, kind=None):
    if category:
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category)
        subcategories = Subcategory.objects.filter(category=category)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category, available=True)
        products_quantity = len(Product.objects.filter(category=category, available=True))

        kinds = None
        if subcategory:
            subcategory = Subcategory.objects.get(slug=subcategory)
            kinds = Kind.objects.filter(kind=subcategory)
            products = Product.objects.filter(category=category, subcategory=subcategory, available=True)

            if kind:
                kind = Kind.objects.filter(slug=kind)
                products = Product.objects.filter(category=category, subcategory=subcategory, kind__in=kind, available=True)

        if products:
            paginator = Paginator(products, 8)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            products = paginator.get_page(page)

        context = {
            'categories':categories,
            'category':category,
            'subcategories':subcategories,
            'subcategory':subcategory,
            'products':products,
            'products_quantity':products_quantity,
            'kinds':kinds
        }

        return render(request, 'shop/product/product_list.html', context)
```

**product_list.html**

```
# Not works
{% if kind %}
    Hello
{% endif %}
```

But if I prescribe such a condition. This work fine

```
{% if category %}
    Hello
{% endif %}
```

Or try this. But not working same

```
{% if category and subcategory and kind %}
    Hello
{% endif %}
```

How do i set conditions for kind? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your if-statement

```
{% if kind %}
Hello
{% endif %}
```

With

```
{% if kinds %}
Hello
{% endif %}
```

in your context Dictionary you declared key value with the name of  **kinds** but in if-statement you are using **kind**

Comment: Thankx alot! Sometimes I also face this crazy type of errors 